# field :published_on, :type => Date; not showing in MongoID + Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, date, mongoid

I have created Model "House".

I followed [this](http://railscasts.com/episodes/238-mongoid) tutorial.

I created my scaffold and I go to my model after I add:

```
field :published_on, :type => Date;
```

Then I see the calendar in views for update the views like tutorial, but when I update the DATE in not appear the date.

I followed the tutorial, but to create or update date not appear.

What's the problem?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Problem fixed!

For every people that working with Date and DateTime in mongoid 2.0 or higher, must add to your model the next code:

```
include Mongoid::MultiParameterAttributes
```

The problem is fixed in this link:

https://github.com/mongoid/mongoid/issues/30#issuecomment-1211911

Answer (score 0):

You manually added the field `:published_on`, did you also add it to `attr_accessible`?

Comment: I had add manually the field :published_on to scaffold. The attr_accessible :published_on not working in mongoid is ignored. Thank you very much